# OpenSSL RSA_sign() returns zero error code

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, rsa, sign

I am playing with OpenSSL 1.0.2o version. I compiled from OpenSSL only static libcrypto. I used this configuration flags:

```
no-demos, no-bugs, no-apps, no-ssl, no-test, no-shared, no-zlib, no-zlib-dynamic, no-ssl-trace, no-unit-test, no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128, no-libunbound, no-ssl1, no-ssl2, no-ssl3, no-asm, no-dtls, no-dtls1, no-threads, no-npn, no-weak-ssl-ciphers, no-rfc3779, no-sctp, no-ui, no-async, no-dgram, no-posix-io, no-sock, no-des, no-dso, no-srp, no-store, no-ts, no-txt_db, no-hw, no-ec, no-gmp, -DOPENSSL_NO_STDIO, -DOPENSSL_NO_FP_API, -DOPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC_ENGINE,-UOPENSSL_FIPS.
```

I use OpenSSL into small embedded device. (without file operations, without operating system and without libc).

I import RSA public and private keys from memory from PEM-strings and then I want to use it for sign/verify, but RSA_sign() function returns zero. May be am I do that wrong?

Import keys:

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

typedef RSA *(*read_bio2rsa_f)(BIO *, RSA **, pem_password_cb *, void *);

static BIO *pub_bio;
static RSA *pub_key;

static BIO *prv_bio;
static RSA *prv_key;

static RSA *openssl_read_key_rsa(int rsa_type, BIO **bio)
{
    RSA *rsa;
    char *pem_str;
    int pem_str_len;
    read_bio2rsa_f read_bio2rsa;

    if (rsa_type == PUB_KEY_TYPE) {
        pem_str = (char *)pem_pub_key;
        pem_str_len = (int)sizeof(pem_pub_key);
        read_bio2rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY;
    } else {
        pem_str = (char *)pem_prv_key;
        pem_str_len = (int)sizeof(pem_prv_key);
        read_bio2rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey;
    }

    if ((*bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((const void *)pem_str,
            pem_str_len)) == NULL) {
        EMSG("BIO_new_mem_buf() FAILED read PEM key");

        return NULL;
    }

    if ((rsa = RSA_new()) == NULL) {
        EMSG("RSA_new() FAILED");

        return NULL;
    }

    read_bio2rsa(*bio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

    return rsa;
}

static int check_rsa_key_pair(RSA *pub, RSA *priv)
{
    if (BN_cmp(pub->n, priv->n) != 0)
        return CRYPTO_ERR;

    return CRYPTO_OK;
}

/* extrnal function for import RSA-keys */
int openssl_rsa_init_key(void)
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf();

    if ((prv_key = openssl_read_key_rsa(PRV_KEY_TYPE, &prv_bio)) == NULL) {
        EMSG("Importing the private key FAILED!");

        return CRYPTO_ERR;
    }

    if ((pub_key = openssl_read_key_rsa(PUB_KEY_TYPE, &pub_bio)) == NULL) {
        EMSG("Importing the public key FAILED!");

        return CRYPTO_ERR;
    }

    if (!check_rsa_key_pair(pub_key, prv_key)) {
        EMSG("Key pair don't match");

        return CRYPTO_ERR;
    }

    EMSG("Import KEYs is successful!");

    return CRYPTO_OK;
}
```

All code above is executed successfully. After this, in theory, I can free use the rsa keys into any OpenSSL functions that expected RSA-type.

I tried to do signature like this:

```
int openssl_rsa_sign_hash(uint8_t *hash, unsigned int hash_len,
        uint8_t *sig, int *sig_len)
{
    if (!RSA_sign(NID_sha256, (const unsigned char *)hash, hash_len,
            (unsigned char *)sig, (unsigned int *)sig_len,
            prv_key)) {
        EMSG("RSA signature FAILED with %s",
            ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

        return CRYPTO_ERR;
    }

    EMSG("RSA signature success!");

    return CRYPTO_OK;
}
```

But, I got "RSA signature FAILED with error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)" this string into my error output.

Could anyone explain me the mistakes, please?

Comment: The only thing I can think of immediately is, does `sig` point to a sufficiently large chunk of available memory, i.e. the same size as the key's modulus?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, hmm...for `sig` buffer I allocate `RSA_size()` bytes. This function returns 256 bytes (2048 bits key). It seems to me rigth.

Comment: May be do I need to search mistake in EGD (Entropy Gathering Daemon) ?

Comment: I have disabled it with help some defines for my target, because it uses file i/o.
`RAND_egd()` don't return true data now.
May be is it important?

Comment: And `RAND_poll()` always returns zero in my system.

Comment: Blinding for private operations (including sign) does use randomness, so lack of it might cause failure -- but AFAICS _should_ give a meaningful error not 0. You might try `RSA_blinding_off(prv_key)` and see if it helps. Of course there are other things for which randomness is vital, so you may need or want to work on that part anyway.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085. I have tried to use `RSA_blinding_off()` for `pub_key` and for `prv_key` and it is works. `RSA_sign` and `RSA_verify` works true, but  I till have trouble with zero code for `RSA_public_encrypt` and `RSA_private_decrypt` functions.

Comment: What padding are you specifying for public_encrypt? Anything other than 'NO' requires randomness -- and encryption with 'NO' padding is insecure for nearly all applications (it wasn't even in PKCS1v1, whereas 'type 0' signatures with no padding were). If you need RSA encryption on this device, you should probably work on fixing the RAND module somehow.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Yes,  i need RSA encryption.  I used pkcs1v5 padding, but for encryption/decryption in my case I have switched it to `no-padding`. But It still doesn't work. It returns zero only. I will try to code my own random module,  thank for your advice:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, I got "RSA signature FAILED with
>   error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)" this string into my error
>   output.
>
> Could anyone explain me the mistakes, please?

I don't see a `main` function, so this is just speculation...

Add a call to `SSL_library_init` and `ERR_load_crypto_strings` in `main`. You may also need a call to `OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers`.

Since you are not getting a good error string, you might try printing the result of `ERR_get_error()`. Once you get the result of `ERR_get_error()`, you can run it through the `openssl errstr` command:

```
$ openssl errstr 0406506C
error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len
```

Also see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.