# Compiling OpenSSL for Embedded ARM on IAR

Tags: c, openssl, arm, embedded, iar

I'm attempting to use the cryptography part of OpenSSL on an embedded device.

I am attempting to add it to an existing project for a Cortex-M4, compiled in IAR. The project does not use an operating system nor file operations. The project has some existing code to use OpenSSL functions (once enabled), so it seems like the obvious crypto library to use.

I thought I might be able to use the necessary cryptographic source files and compile them in IAR, but the dependencies seem to get out of control, and some files do not exist yet (EG opensslconf.h). I have read the INSTALL file and done a lot of googling but I am still completely confused about how to approach this.

Here is a related post which suggests it is possible. [OpenSSL RSA_sign() returns zero error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302636/openssl-rsa-sign-returns-zero-error-code)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try to compile it for PC and look at the size of binary . you will see footprint which is way too big for your purpose. did you look at mbed TLS ( https://tls.mbed.org/ )?

Comment: If you're flexible, I can very much recommend mbedtls as an alternative. It is particularly designed for embedded applications and very easily configurable.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have looked at MBED TLS and have downloaded and done a little work with it. I will re-visit that and try again.

Comment: Try using WolfSSL, they have small footprint and also have wrapper functions for OpenSSL function calls.

Comment: I considered WolfSSL but the licensing was not going to work for the product. Thanks!